# Tagging String positions

Tags: java

How should I go about tagging char positions of a String?

For example, I have a String 'string' and changed 'str' to 'flam' to become 'flaming'. I want to tag the 'flam' part that's been replaced. What is the best way to do this in java?

Further Example:

The string starts off having no tags meaning nothing has been replaced. r is then tagged to those replaced before.

string -> flaming

------  ->  rrrr---

and if I continue to change

flaming -> flamiche

rrrr--- -> rrrr-rrr

Comment: What exactly do you mean by tagging?

Answer (score 0):

i think..

use int position = String.indexOf() method for getting String position.

and flam + String.SubString(position).

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, int[]> tagDetails = new HashMao<String, int[]>();
```

The array can be of length 2, with start and end index of `tag` in the `key` string.

However, it doesn't solve the duplicate key problem.

OR

you can create a custom object similar to following:

```
class TaggedObject
{
    int objId;
    String theString;
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;
}
```

Comment: A `Map<String, List<Integer[]>>` seems to manage the duplicate key problem.

Comment: @sp00m: ya, but still sequence might be an issue. i.e. which tag to use for given string.